# Getting a distinct values array of a big Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of ~8M documents. Each document is of the following format, for example:

```
doc_1: {'_id':..., 'user_name': 'bla1', 'predicted_class': 'class_1}
doc_2: {'_id':..., 'user_name': 'bla2', 'predicted_class': 'class_2}
```

While the 'user_name' field is a contains unique values and 'predicted_class' doesn't.

I'm trying to get distinct user names of a certain predicted class. In some cases (where a class of predicted_class has a few documents) I'm getting the distinct values but in most it's just loading and loading (disk and memory usage up high) but doesn't end.

Iv'e tried to use the simple

```
db.getCollection('predictions').find({'predicted_class': 'class_a'}).distinct('user_name')
```

as well as

but no luck out there.

The issue arises as a result of the collection size and I understand that a different approach must be taken (map reduce perhaps) but my Mongodb understanding is limited unfortunately.

How should I approach this issue?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#examples

Comment: See also the manual page for [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). You don't "chain" the methods, but rather include the query condition **within** the `distinct()` method itself. Various examples on the linked duplicate in other answers other than the accepted one, which lacks a query predicate. Also `$group` with aggregation can be used with a `$match` for similar results.